Would a straight bridge seem bent to the human eye?
I'm not really sure whether this is more biology or physics, probably it's relevant.
Consider a perfectly straight bridge (straight as a light ray) tangent to the earth surface at some point. We know it is "bent upwards" in terms of gravity potential: the parts further from the point of contact has higher gravity potential. Would it seem to be bent to the human eye?

I don't know what human psychology may be relevant to determine the subjective experience of a human observer in this case. But as far as the basic physics is concerned, you have answered the question already by saying the bridge is "straight as a light ray". So if I stand at one end of the bridge, and carefully look along it (which is a good and natural way to try to determine how straight it is) then I would see all parts of the bridge along the line I am looking along (moving my eye to and fro a little  to get a sense of this). Therefore it would look straight under that kind of inspection.
Looking from the side, from some distance away, I guess it would look pretty straight, and I might hold up a straight object to see if it lines up with what I can see of the bridge.
It is widely reported that people can see, by naked eye, that the Earth is curved when they view the
horizon from a mountaintop or aeroplane,
in good atmospheric conditions. They would be able to tell that a long enough bridge was not following the horizon. They may well then infer that such a bridge is straight, or possibly straight.
